# How do I get information /proc/$pid/smaps

Tags: linux, bash, memory-management, sh, pid

I have to make a bash script that kick `/proc/$pid/smaps` the following information and not as:

```
total memory: 2mb

Memory resident: 3kb

private memory + shared: 3kb

Private total memory: 5kb
```

How do I access the data and add the cantiades? 
if I do a `cat / proc / $ pid / smaps` gives me all the lines of the file and do not know how to select only those you want.

Comment: maybe by reading your linux lessons, seems like a homework. What have you tested ? have you tried with grep ? awk ? anything else ?

Comment: I started with cat / proc / $ pid / smaps
then

cat / proc / $ pid / smaps | while read

but not to identify file fields

Comment: I started with cat / proc / $ pid / smaps
then

cat / proc / $ pid / smaps | while read

but not to identify file fields


how do I remove the first line of the file from the rest?

08048000-080bc000 r-xp 00000000 03:02 13130      /bin/bash
Size:               1084 kB
Rss:                 892 kB
Pss:                 374 kB
Shared_Clean:        892 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:          892 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to get specific lines with pattern matching, for example:

```
grep -e ^Private -e ^Rss -e ^Pss /path/to/proc
```

An equivalent, shorter, but less portable way:

```
grep -E '^(Private|Rss|Pss)' /path/to/proc
```

You can use `sed` to print specific lines by line number:

```
# print 5th line
sed -ne 5p
# print from 5th line until the end of file
sed -ne '5,$p'
# print everything except the 5th line (= delete the 5th line)
sed -e 5d
```

You can use `tail` to print from 2nd line until the end of file (= ignore the first line):

```
tail +2 /path/to/proc
```

I hope this covers your needs.